# Get total value until current month?

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully fetch data using query below.

```
$sql2 = "Select element,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 'Jan' THEN total ELSE 0 END ) AS Jan,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 'Feb' THEN total ELSE 0 END ) AS Feb,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 'Mac' THEN total ELSE 0 END ) AS Mac //until december
from tbl_macscstate
group by element";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$getRec2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2);
```

Now, my problem is I want to add value from July untill current month and I have no idea how to do it. Can someone point me to the right direction. Below code is how i display the data in table.

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['element']; ?></div></td>   
    <?php if( $year != '2014' ){ ?>
    <?php if( 1 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Jan']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 2 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Feb']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 3 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Mac']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 4 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Apr']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 5 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['May']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 6 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Jun']; ?></div></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if( 7 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Jul']; ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( 8 <= $monthID ): ?><td><?php echo $row['Aug']; ?></td><?php endif; ?> //until Dec
    <td><div align="center" style="color:black"><?php //echo YTD; ?></td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? A new column in your select that returns the requested calculation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this function will do the job:

```
<?php    
    function getSumBetweenMonths($month1,$month2,$row)
    {           
        $m2i=array('Jan'=>1,'Feb'=>2,'Mar'=>3,'Apr'=>4,'May'=>5,'Jun'=>6,'Jul'=>7,'Aug'=>8,'Sep'=>9,'Oct'=>10,'Nov'=>11,'Dec'=>12);
        $i2m=array(1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar',4=>'Apr',5=>'May',6=>'Jun',7=>'Jul',8=>'Aug',9=>'Sep',10=>'Oct',11=>'Nov',12=>'Dec');
        $sum=0;
        $i=$m2i[$month1];
        $j=$m2i[$month2];
        if(!$i||!$j)Die("Unknown months $month1,$month2");
        for(;;)
        {
            $sum+=$row[$i2m[$i]];
            if($i==$j) return $sum;
            $i++;
            if($i>=13) $i=1;
        }
    }

    echo getSumBetweenMonths('Jul',date('M'),$row);  
?>
```